# multiple string queries on a single table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

making a site for game trailers and on the front page I organize the games in terms of their category, so I end up doing this (rails):

```
  def index
    @newGames = Game.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    @casualGames = Game.where("category = 'casual'").limit(9)
    @actionGames = Game.where("category = 'action'").limit(8)
    @strategyGames = Game.where("category = 'strategy'").limit(9)
    @adventureGames = Game.where("category = 'adventure'").limit(8)
    @puzzleGames = Game.where("category = 'puzzle'").limit(9)
  end
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing but without making 6 separate queries on the sable table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your search parameters are different querying DB multiple times is unavoidable. However you can make your controller skinny. Create a class method in Game class and collect and return everything you need in a hash.

**Game.rb**

```
def self.for_index_page
    games = {}
    games.merge!(new: order("created_at DESC").limit(3))
    games.merge!(casual: category_with_limit('casual', 9)
    games.merge!(action: category_with_limit('action', 8)
    ...
end

def self.category_with_limit(category, limit)
    where(category: category).limit(limit)
end
```

**GamesController.rb**

```
def index
    @games = Game.for_index_page
end
```

**index.erb**

```
<%=@games[:new] %>
<%=@games[:casual] %>

...
```